# Estimating value of 1/pi using Ramajunam equation, returning wrong value when comparing with (1/math.pi)

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

**Edited for Updated code**

@racraman. Love you man. You not only helped me improve my code but also to understand the Equation. Thanks for your time.

```
import math
# performing ramanujan's infinite series to 
#generate a numerical approximation of 1/pi:
""" 1/pi = (2*sqrt(2))/9801) * (4*k)!*(1103+26390k)/(((k!)**4)*396**(4k)))"""

def factorial_1(k):
    if k==0:
        return 1
    else:
        result = k* factorial_1(k-1)
        return result

def estimate_pi():
    k=0
    total=0
    n=(2*math.sqrt(2)/9801)
    limit=int(input("Enter the ending limit = ")) #k=0 until limit=infinity!!!!
    while True:
        m=factorial_1(4*k)*(1103+26390*k)
        o=((factorial_1(k))**4)*(396**(4*k))
        result=n*(m/o)
        total+=result #assigning result to a new variable to keep track of changes
        if k>limit:
            break
        k+=1 #updating value of k, to improve result & total for each loop.
    return 1/total # Return's pi=3.14 only if k=0
print(estimate_pi())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement :

```
k = result
```

is the problem - the variable k cannot be both a loop counter and the running total.

Instead of that statement, you will need to simply decrement k, and also add `result` to a new running total variable that you initialise to 0 outside the loop.

You would also only want to print the result and return only after the loop has finished.

**EDIT TO ADD :**

Please don't use Answers in that way;  that's not what they're for, and would be confusing for other readers to try to follow.  The question is for containing all (ongoing) steps of defining the problem (just mark the appended updates with "EDIT TO ADD" as I have done with this comment);  the answers are for solutions to that problem, to be accepted if they proved useful.

Ramanujan's formula most certainly works for increasing values of k - but you have to iterate starting at 0.

For example, let's say the user enters 5 for k.

What your code is currently doing is incrementing k - so calculating k = 5, 6, 7, ..... terminating when the step's result is 0.  You're missing out k=0, 1, 2, 3, 4 - the major terms !

What you want to do instead is sum the results for k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 so how about :

- Have the user enter a variable `limit` instead of k
- Start k at 0, and increment at each iteration
- Terminate the loop when the step's result < epsilon, or `k > limit`

Incidentally, the `n=(2*math.sqrt(2)/9801)` is a constant, so can go outside the loop therefore get calculated only once.

Comment: Thanks helped a lot. Have started using a  ` total=0` to assign the result to. Plus have made obervation **that this equation work only for k=0**. for other values of K the pi value is wrong. Please let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Great - some progress :).  Could you edit the question to add your updated code.

Comment: Have answered using my updated code to keep track of the mistakes I've made along the way.

Comment: **Have edited the question with updated code.** Thanks for helping me understand the equation.

Answer (score 1):

@racraman. I'm Posting the updated code as an answer do that I could keep track of the Error's I've made for future references. Thanks for the Help.

```
# performing ramanujan's infinite series to 
#generate a numerical approximation of 1/pi:
""" 1/pi = (2*sqrt(2))/9801) * (4*k)!*(1103+26390k)/(((k!)**4)*396**(4k)))"""

def factorial_1(k):
    if k==0:
        return 1
    else:
        result = k* factorial_1(k-1)
        return result

def estimate_pi():
    k=int(input("enter the value of k = "))
    total=0
    while True:
        n=(2*math.sqrt(2)/9801)
        m=factorial_1(4*k)*(1103+26390*k)
        o=((factorial_1(k))**4)*(396**(4*k))
        result=n*(m/o)
        total+=result #assigning result to a new variable to keep track of changes
        epsilon=1e-15
        if abs(result)<epsilon:
            break
        k+=1 #updating value of k, to improve result & total for each loop.
    return 1/total # Return's pi=3.14 only if k=0
print(estimate_pi())
```